# Running post-build event ONLY in build definition

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msbuild, build-definition

In our web project, we've modified the .csproj file to run this command pre-build:

```
cd $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)
npm run build-release
cd $(MSBuildStartupDirectory)
```

It works just fine.

The problem is that we don't want this in the .csproj anymore. We only want it in the build definition.

I can't figure out. This is what I have, and I get errors about the path being too long.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's a pre-build **script**. You can run batch files or PowerShell scripts, not command line utilities. The script should be a source controlled artifact, and the path to the script file should be a source control location, not a local path on the build agent.

Comment: Are you sure you can run batch files?